# Visual Studio: Difference between "Save all changes" and "Save Changes To Open Documents Only"?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to make sense of the Visual Studio options: What's the difference between "Save all changes" and "Save Changes To Open Documents Only"?

[image]

How could you have unsaved changes in a document while it is NOT open in the IDE?

Comment: Maybe from a Search In Files operation? Previous versions used to either open all affected files, or save them right away, but maybe VS2010 can hold the modified files in memory without having them visually "open"? Just guessing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably related to project files, solution files, and other files which are automatically changed without having to do any editing in a file.

If those files are under source control the effect of what is saved is much more obvious.